# Add extra height to border-box when height is percentage

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: fill;
  height: 3.5vh;
  min-height: 30px;
  border-left: 1px solid #4B4A4A;
  border-top: 1px solid #4B4A4A;
  position: relative;
}

.test {
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: green; 
  height: 600%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid"></div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="test"></div>
</div></div>
<div class="grid"></div>
<div class="grid"></div>
```

Here is how that looks
[image: Image of css]

Now, what I want is that the test class has a border within the border of the grids and that by having the height as 600%, that it would fit exactly within the 6th grid. However, it doesn't fit because of the 5 borders of the grids. So what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use box-sizing: border-box in both your classes.

Without changing much of your code :

```css
.grid {
        display: grid;
        height: 3.5vh;
        min-height: 30px;
        border-left: 1px solid #4B4A4A;
        border-top: 1px solid #4B4A4A;
        position: relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
            
    .test {
        top: 0;
        opacity: 80%;
        position: absolute;        

      box-sizing: border;
      background-color: green; 
        min-height: 180px;
        height: 600%;
        
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        
        z-index: 0;

}
```

```html
 <div class="grid"></div>
                <div class="grid"><div class="test"></div></div></div>
                <div class="grid"></div>
                <div class="grid"></div>
                <div class="grid"></div>
                <div class="grid"></div>
                <div class="grid"></div>
                <div class="grid"></div>
```